# Devise preserve original path during sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, warden

I have a case where two requests(iframes) are made by browser to a rails app (rails 3.2, devise 2.2.0), both initiate sign in (through SSO) and then render the requested page. Problem is that there is a race condition for `session[:user_return_to]` and both of the pages render same page so one of the iframes end up rendering wrong page.

This is the flow of the app right now

1. `authenticate_user!` method is called and devise redirects to `/users/sign_in` page
2. `SessionsController#new` processes the request and instead on rendering it redirects to `/sso/new`
3. Request comes back in from SSO to `/sso/create` which sign user in (in devise) and redirects to requested page

On step 2, I can pass a URL as a param to `/sso/new` and that param will be returned back to me during step 3. Problem is that referrer is already lost when I'm in `SessionsController#new`. All I have there is `session[:user_return_to]` which already has wrong value for one of the iframes (session is shared and race condition occurs).

I was wondering if the referrer can be passed on somehow through warden failure. I was not able to see if there is a hook to pass it as param or header through warden when executing `authenticate_user!` before filter. During that request I have referrer but warden doesnt preserve it when it redirects to `/users/sign_in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using custom failure app for warden.

I used `request.original_fullpath` in redirect_url and it worked.

here is my failure class

```
class CustomDeviseFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    if sso_enabled?
      sso_path(return_to: request.original_fullpath)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def sso_enabled?
    true
  end
end
```